# Duplicate color indicator in CSS files in Visual Studio Code - how can I find out why?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have several extensions installed and now have 2 color indicators in front of every color in CSS files - one is more than sufficient ;-)

The first indicator comes from the extension "color highlight" - which does just what I want.
how can I know which extensions the second indicator is from? This is what it looks like with the second indicator.

[image]

Any Idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be through the Extensions view to disable extensions
by order of pertinence until the icon disappears.

To temporarily disable an extension, click the gear button to the right of its entry,
globally or for the current Workspace.

Since you will be prompted to reload VS Code after disabling an extension,
it might be better to disable them in bunches.

For more information see
[Disable an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_disable-an-extension).